# React (Jest tests for tr element Unable to find element...tbody)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to test my component i.e

`<TableRow key={1} name={name} />` which renders into

```
<tr>
    <td>{this.props.name}</td>
</tr>
```

Looks like this in test file

```
const mockName = { }

const mockPopularSearchLitItem = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(TableRow name={mockName} />)
```

However I get the following error when I try to run the test

**Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., .0): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a `<tbody>` when using tables, nesting tags like `<form>`, `<p>`, or `<a>`, or using non-SVG elements in an  parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this post http://codeheaven.io/testing-react-components-with-enzyme/ it is not possible to test test   in isolation.

It might be a better way of testing given that

> Shallow rendering let us render our component without touching the DOM. It also let us test our component as a unit, since it renders our component only one-level deep. Errors in children components wouldn’t propagate to top level components, making our tests more isolated and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a dummy table:

```
// Create dummy table to render table rows inside
const Table = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Table',
  render: function() {
    return (<table><tbody>{this.props.children}</tbody></table>);
  }
});
const mockPopularSearchList = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Table><TableRow name={mockName} /></Table>);
```